# What laws can be used by the Indian government to ban a film or documentary?

Tags: law, india

The Indian government has banned a controversial [BBC documentary](https://www.nbcnews.com/video/bbc-documentary-on-pm-modi-draws-ire-in-india-161913925579) about Narendra Modi, claiming it is propaganda. [This *Guardian* article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/jan/23/india-emergency-laws-to-ban-bbc-narendra-modi-documentary) claims that they invoked their emergency laws to ban it.

The question is, what *are* the emergency laws of India? Is there an article in the constitution which outlines the laws of emergency?

Comment: Any state in the world, or any state in India? Different governments have different very different rules regarding what others might call censorship. There are almost 200 countries in the world. Asking for a compilation of the censorship laws in each one is asking too much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too broad.

Comment: I've edited the question to narrow it down to just India's emergency laws, as those are the ones you actually seem to be asking about. As David Hammen explained above, asking about the emergency laws of *every country in the world* is much too broad. Only India's is actually relevant to the example you brought up.

Comment: Even now it seems really broad as there can be vastly different reasons to ban a film/documentary based on the content of it.

Comment: Amusingly enough, I seem to recall a number of Indian emergency laws were.... inherited from the British colonial administration.  That said, maybe more a Q for SE.Law?

Comment: https://www.hrw.org/news/2022/07/18/sedition-law-why-india-should-break-britains-abusive-legacy

Comment: @DavidHammen I have specifically asked for Indian government in my question?

Comment: @Up-In-Air No, you didn't. "State" has multiple meanings. In one sense, India is a "state", as are France, the United Kingdom, Canada, etc. This is, for example, the meaning used by the United Nations. In another sense, "state" refers to various parts of India (or the US, or Mexico, or other countries that refer to constituent elements as "states"). In any case, it apparently wasn't individual states in India that banned that film. It was the country as a whole.

Comment: @DavidHammen true agree, it was later modified to specific state India, which is what I really wanto undersatnd. When Indian govt banned the BBC documentary, what laws were evoked or the govt has the right to ban any foreign content calling it a false propaganda.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica s link answers my question to certain extent that it's sedition law that is used to ban this documentary, if anybody feels otherwise please correct me.

Comment: have you tried looking at Indian newspapers rather than Guardian?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I read this https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/sc-agrees-to-hear-plea-challenging-centre-s-decision-to-ban-bbc-documentary-101675056807863.html this talks about the plea for removing the ban, no articles describe why the ban was imposed

Comment: @Up-In-Air From the Guardian article, India ranks 150 out of 180 regarding freedom of the press. This can only mean that this is not anywhere close to an isolated incident. Criticism of India apparently is highly frowned upon in India. Some countries tolerate criticism while others do not. India does not, given that low of a ranking.

Comment: Countries that do not tolerate dissent or criticism can make up whatever excuse they want for shutting down dissent or criticism. This might even mean alledgedly killing dissenting journalists. (I'm referring to Saudi Arabia, not India). Other countries are also alleged to have killed dissenting journalists.

Comment: @DavidHammen  The press freedom ranking is a biased western indicator, which lacks objectivity and transparency. It was irrelevant to mention it here.

Comment: @whoisit Call it biased, call it whatever you want. That said, a ridiculously low ranking of 150 out of 180 means something, and it is not a good something. A ranking that low simply is not a good sign. India does not have and has not had a good reputation regarding freedom of speech. **Officially** banning a BBC production is but one example, and it justifies their low ranking.

Comment: @whoisit here's a deal: you tell me what to write on a sign and go protest in front of the White House, I tell you what to write on yours and go protest in front of your the Parliament of your favorite non-Western country. Do you see why this will be very easy for me but very hard for you? This is why David is right and Press Freedom ratings are legitimate, even if biased.

Comment: @JonathanReez My point was that the press freedom ranking is irrelevant to this question and answer; specifically since it lacks objectivity and transparency, it is just an opinion (like yours). The question specifically asks about facts - i.e. which laws were invoked - not about someone's opinion of those laws.

Comment: If we're allowed to talk about something as stupid as the PFI rankings, here are some much more legitimate facts: 
The Supreme Court of India already acquitted Modi of the allegations that the documentary was making and this was when a fiercely anti-Modi government, the UPA-II, was in power.   
Moreover, the timing of this documentary is sinister. It has coincided with India assuming the G-20 presidency, while the UK India FTA talks are going on and there is a PM of Indian origin at 10 Downing Street.

Comment: @whoisit I agree with your comments, but it does relate to the question as to why Indian govt imposed a ban on that documentary. There has to be some legal explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The following is just re-iterating information in public domain.

Article 19 of the constitution of India guarantees the Freedom of speech and expression as a Fundamental Right - however, with quite a few restrictions.

1. The right is available *only* to the citizens of India - the BBC  is not an Indian citizen.
2. The constitution allows government to have reasonable restrictions on the exercise of the right - specifically in the interests of 
   i. the sovereignty and integrity of India, 
   ii. the security of the State, 
   iii. friendly relations with foreign States, 
   iv. public order, decency or morality, 
   or in relation to contempt of court, defamation or incitement to an offence.

On Jan 20, the central government used this restriction, and banned the documentary, with officials saying it has been found to be “undermining the sovereignty and integrity of India” and has “the potential to adversely impact” the country’s “friendly relations with foreign states” and “public order within the country”.

The Secretary, Information and Broadcasting Ministry had issued the directions in his capacity as Authorised Officer under Rule 13(2) of The IT Rules 2021 to take down all online presence of the documentary in India.

Comment: The problem here, compared to your assertion that Press Freedom Index is a "biased western indicator" is that, from a Western PoV, the *reasonable restrictions*  you list are numerous and seem pretty much left to the interpretation of the government.  Specifically items like "decency or morality" would raise huge red flags to Western voters.  That 150 out of 180 hardly seems out of reach.  Furthermore how banning a still-available-to-foreigners documentary to Indians would avoid damage to "friendly relations with foreign states” is really questionable.  Certainly avoid embarrassing Modi tho.

Comment: @whoisit How was this restriction conveyed to the nation, was there a press briefing  on Jan 20th, any video, text links from the Ministry of Braodcasting